# ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently in the process of testing a multi-step form using Python Selenium. While the browser initializes correctly and progresses through the required steps, I've encountered an intermittent issue related to the next button redirect, resulting in an ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM error. Strangely, this behavior is inconsistent: sometimes the redirect works perfectly, other times the second redirect fails, and occasionally the third redirect also fails.

Could this problem be attributed to a flaw in my Selenium instance?

Here's the initialization function I'm using:

```py
def initialize_instance():
    platform = sys.platform
    if platform.startswith("win"):
        ser = Service(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
    elif platform == "darwin":
        ser = Service(r"/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

    caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    caps["loggingPrefs"] = {"browser": "ALL"}
    caps["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    op.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    # op.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
    op.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    op.add_argument("--accept-untrusted-certs")
    op.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op,
                              desired_capabilities=caps)

    # Implizite Wartezeit von 10 Sekunden setzen
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    return driver
```

Additionally, here's a snippet of my code responsible for clicking the next button and navigating to the next page:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'next')]").click()
```

I'm curious as to why this issue is occurring and whether there are any steps I can take to address it effectively.